# How to create a salary payslip form just with power query in excel?

Tags: excel, powerquery

Is there any way to create salary payslip form just with power query and relationships between tables in excel instead of using a bunch of vlookup functions?

I intend to create a payroll accounting program in Excel and I need to create a payslip form (Salary slip).

On my first worksheet in the workbook, I have a large table of employees salary info with multiple columns and rows (roughly a 1000 rows and 10 columns) and in another worksheet (payslip sheet) I've already created a payslip form with the help of vlookup and drop-down menu of employees unic Id number but everytime I need to add a new column to employees salary info sheet everything is messing up and I have to edit every vlookup function from scratch.

I contemplate that every time I choose an employee's name from a drop-down list, then his or her data automatically shows the payslip report.

In the end, I'm really eager to know any creative solution or your special advice about this issue, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try using index/match in place of vlookup so that your formulas automatically adjust when adding new columns to the source data

In example below rather than using

```
=VLOOKUP("Bob",$A$1:$D$4,3,FALSE)
```

Use

```
=INDEX(C2:C4,MATCH("Bob",A2:A4,0))
```

If you added columns between B:D, it would not impact the index/match version, but the vlookup version would return the wrong value

Coming soon is XLOOKUP() function in certain versions of excel, which will replace the need for index/match

[image: illustraion of index match in excel]